# Indexes on BLOBs that contain encrypted data

Tags: mysql, encryption, indexing, blob, aes

I have a bunch of columns in a table that are of the type BLOB. The data that's contained in these columns are encrypted with MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT() function. Some of these fields are being used in a search section of an application I'm building. Is it worth it to put indexes on the columns that are being frequently accessed? I wasn't sure if the fact that they are BLOBs or the fact that the data itself is encrypted would make an index useless.

EDIT: Here are some more details about my specific case. There is a table with ~10 columns or so that are each BLOBs. Each record that is inserted into this table will be encrypted using the AES_ENCRYPT() function. In the search portion of my application users will be able to type in their query. I take their query and decrypt it like this `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(fname MYSTATICKEY) AS fname FROM some_table` so that I can perform a search using a LIKE clause. What I am curious about is if the index will index the encrypted data and not the actual data that is returned from the decryption. I am guessing that if the index applied to only the encrypted binary string then it would not help performance at all. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: You'll be indexing them up to a certain length(specified in SQL) only. And comparisons have to be within that length. IMO

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your use case? I have a few ideas but it depends how you are searching.

Comment: Sure, I've added more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following:

- You can't add an index of type `FULLTEXT` to a BLOB column (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html)
- Therefore, you will need to use another type of index. For BLOBs, you will have to specify a prefix length (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) - the length will depend on the storage engine (e.g. up to 1000 bytes long for MyISAM tables, and 767 bytes for InnoDB tables). Therefore, unless the values you are storing are short you won't be able to index all the data.
- AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts a string and returns a binary string. This binary string will be the value that is indexed.

Therefore, IMO, your guess is right - an index won't help the performance of your searches.

Note that 'indexing an encrypted column' is a fairly common problem - there's quite few articles online about it. For example (although this is quite old and for MS SQL it does cover some ideas): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2006/03/11/549754.aspx

Also see: [What's the best way to store and yet still index encrypted customer data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961603/whats-the-best-way-to-store-and-yet-still-index-encrypted-customer-data) (the top answer links to the same article I found above)