# Is it considered a bad practice to use the same initial vector for encryption although I have to

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs, node-crypto

I am making an application that has the **national id** of a user as a column, sure this data is sensitive so it has to be encrypted so I am using node JS crypto library for encryption and using the `createCipheriv` method to encrypt it as `createCipher` is deprecated. what's making me want to make the **initial vector** constant is that I want the users to register with their **national Id** first will search if that national id is available in my database then allow them to register if available the point here is that I will need to search the **national id** in the database so I can't add initial vectors to it as it will be impossible to find, so is this OK as I have to do so or there is a better way to do it?

**NOTE:** The point of using `createCipheriv` in the first place is that I might need to decrypt it later.

Comment: You should not use a constant IV for security reasons. Instead, you could search using an index based on an HMAC or a reliable key derivation function like Argon2 or PBKDF2, see e.g.  [here](https://itnext.io/indexing-encrypted-database-field-for-searching-e50e7bcfbd80) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4961603).

Comment: Thanks for the reply that really helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you really ought not to re-use an IV. Your solution indicates the id is sensitive, so that should not be an IV. Can you store an IV as another column? It does not need to be encrypted. The IV must be unique, that's the only requirement. You could use an incrementing value or a GUID, something like that that's guaranteed unique